# How to do add multiple desktop links to same application - Updated

Tags: install4j

I need add multiple desktop links to same Application for provide different arguments.

What is the java code which is executed in "Add a desktop Link" install4j action?

(Update)

I have found the code which create a simple desktop Link in windows. Now I have test with a for loop to create multiple instances with different arguments, but method return always false in status flag for next executions (I think that this method not flush shortCut File and it is blocked for next iterations).

This is the code:

```
import com.install4j.api.windows.WinFileSystem;

int[] listIndexDestinos = (int[])context.getVariable("listIndexDestinosSeleccionados");     //int array with indexs of javax.swing.JList selected
String[] listDestinosDisponibles = (String[])context.getVariable("listDestinosDisponibles");//String array with description for Destinations. Index related with previous array.

String installationDir = (String)context.getVariable("sys.installationDir");
String executableFile = "app.exe";
String executableAbsolutePath = installationDir + File.separatorChar + executableFile;

String iconsDir = installationDir + File.separatorChar + "icons" + File.separatorChar; 
File shortcutTo = new File(executableAbsolutePath);
File startIn =  new File(installationDir);

String strDesktopDir = (String)context.getVariable("sys.desktopDir");
for (int index : listIndexDestinos) {
    String nombreConf = listDestinosDisponibles[index];
    String iconName = "icon_" + index + ".ico";    
    String arguments = "-cfg "+index;
    String descripcion = "APP - "+nombreConf;
    String inkLocation = strDesktopDir + File.separatorChar + "App - " + nombreConf + ".lnk";
    File inkFile = new File(inkLocation);
    File iconFile = new File(iconsDir + iconName);        
    boolean created = WinFileSystem.createShellLink(inkFile,shortcutTo,iconFile,arguments,descripcion,startIn);
    Util.showMessage("Crear acceso directo. inkLocation: "+inkLocation+". arguments: "+arguments+". created: "+created);
}
return true;
```

Comment: I dont' Know Why I have a negative post.

In install4j exist an action for Finish process, named "Add a Desktop Link", with you can add a Link to desktop with arguments.

I want use a multi-selection list, in which user can select multiple values, and create a desktop link for each.

So, what was wrong?

Comment: @YvetteColomb How is this off topic? It has the correct tag and it's a valid question. By closing it, you have prevented me from answering it. Please do the right thing and reopen it.

Comment: @Lundin I would like to answer this questions and IMO there was no good reason for closing it. I would appreciate if you could help me to reopen it.

Comment: @Petter Friberg I would like to answer this questions and IMO there was no good reason for closing it. I would appreciate if you could help me to reopen it.

Comment: @Tunaki I would like to answer this questions and IMO there was no good reason for closing it. I would appreciate if you could help me to reopen it.

Comment: @Termininja I would like to answer this questions and IMO there was no good reason for closing it. I would appreciate if you could help me to reopen it.

Comment: I have found the class that creates desktop links in windows: **com.install4j.api.windows.WinFileSystem**, method: **createShellLink**

But I can't add more that 1 desktop file, since after that I get always return flag as false.

I could add example code now.

Could you reopen this post?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yes I have cast the vote to reopen it. I think it's sad that valid questions are closed without good reason.

Comment: @SantiagoNietoCarrera Please contact support@ej-technologies.com, I have a build for you where this is fixed.